# Docker Desktop for windows fails on search/build with corporate proxy

Tags: windows, docker, proxy, docker-desktop

I have installed Docker Desktop for windows `Docker version 18.09.2, build 6247962`, and I'm not able to build and image. Even a `docker search` does not seem to work.

The error message (for example, when doing a `docker search`) is:

```
Error response from daemon: Get https://index.docker.io/v1/search?q=ubuntu&n=25: proxyconnect tcp: dial tcp 172.17.14.133:3128: connect: no route to host
```

My office is behind a proxy. So on the "Proxies" settings of DockerDesktop I set `http://172.17.14.133:3128` for both HTTP and HTTTPS. But it still does not seem to work.

I have defined some ENV variables (both user and system) like this:

```
HTTPS_PROXY=http://proxypmi.tradyso.com:3128
HTTP_PROXY=http://proxypmi.tradyso.com:3128
```

Also:

`C:\Users\my.user\AppData\Roaming\Docker\http_proxy.json`:

```
{
  "http": "http://172.17.14.133:3128",
  "https": "http://172.17.14.133:3128",
  "exclude": null,
  "transparent_http_ports": [],
  "transparent_https_ports": []
}
```

`C:\Users\my.user\AppData\Roaming\Docker\settings.json`:

```
{
  "settingsVersion": 1,
  "autoStart": false,
  "checkForUpdates": true,
  "analyticsEnabled": false,
  "displayedWelcomeWhale": true,
  "displayed14393Deprecation": false,
  "displayRestartDialog": true,
  "displaySwitchWinLinContainers": true,
  "latestBannerKey": "",
  "debug": false,
  "memoryMiB": 2048,
  "swapMiB": 1024,
  "cpus": 2,
  "diskPath": null,
  "diskSizeMiB": 64000000000,
  "networkCIDR": "10.0.75.0/24",
  "proxyHttpMode": true,
  "overrideProxyHttp": "http://172.17.14.133:3128",
  "overrideProxyHttps": "http://172.17.14.133:3128",
  "overrideProxyExclude": null,
  "useDnsForwarder": true,
  "dns": "10.44.24.10",
  "kubernetesEnabled": false,
  "showKubernetesSystemContainers": false,
  "kubernetesInitialInstallPerformed": false,
  "cliConfigCreationDate": "03/22/2019 12:23:58",
  "linuxDaemonConfigCreationDate": "03/22/2019 12:22:19",
  "windowsDaemonConfigCreationDate": null,
  "versionPack": "default",
  "sharedDrives": {},
  "executableDate": "",
  "useWindowsContainers": false,
  "swarmFederationExplicitlyLoggedOut": false,
  "activeOrganizationName": null,
  "exposeDockerAPIOnTCP2375": false
}
```

`C:\Users\my.user\.docker\config.json`:

```
{
  "stackOrchestrator": "swarm",
  "auths": {},
  "credsStore": "wincred",
  "proxies":
  {
    "default":
    {
      "httpProxy": "http://172.17.14.133:3128",
      "httpsProxy": "http://172.17.14.133:3128",
      "noProxy": ""
    }
  }
}
```

I also tried passing `build-arg` to `tocker build`:

```
docker build --build-arg HTTP_PROXY=http://172.17.14.133:3128 --build-arg HTTPS_PROXY=http://172.17.14.133:3128 ...
```

Finally, on the Docker Desktop network configuration, I have tried with DNSs both "Automatic" and Manual (Using my corporate dns servers)

None of this has worked.

Any hint on what should I do?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A collegue found out the problem:

By default, the bridge network that docker creates uses the same subnet as our office (172.17.0.0/16) and that causes trouble with the proxy ip address (172.17.14.133).

To solve this:

---

**[Edit]:** for a simpler method, use the following:

On daemon configuration, add `"bip": "new_subbet"`. For example: `"bip": "172.19.0.1/16"`. Then, restart docker.

Now, you won't even need to pass the extra `--network="docker_gwbridge"` parameter to the commands.

This shorter solution may not work with older versions of Docker for windows, so you may consider the original answer if this option does not work.

---

**[Edit]:** original method for old versions of docker for windows:

The bridge network cannot be deleted, but We can tell docker not to create it.

Go to Daemon Settings, Advanced => add `"bridge": "none",` to the configuration

After applying changes, Docker will restart and now We will be able to create our own custom bridge network

In this example, We are going to use (172.19.0.0/16)

Open a console and write:

```
docker network create --subnet=172.19.0.0/16 --gateway 172.19.0.1 -o com.docker.network.bridge.enable_icc=true -o com.docker.network.bridge.name=docker_gwbridge -o com.docker.network.bridge.enable_ip_masquerade=true docker_gwbridge
```

Then we can do a `docker ls` for checking that the previous command was successful:

```
$ docker network ls
 
NETWORK ID          NAME                DRIVER              SCOPE
2a3635a49ffa        docker_gwbridge     bridge              local
4e9ec758ee9f        host                host                local
737c6c5fc82b        none                null                local
```

Now do a `docker search ubuntu` (for example). It should be able to connect to the internet and fetch the images.

**Important:** From now on, some commands that need internet access will need to specify the new docker network with the extra parameter `--network="docker_gwbridge"`

For example a docker build command could be:

```
docker build --network="docker_gwbridge" --build-arg http_proxy=http://172.17.14.133:3128 --build-arg https_proxy=http://172.17.14.133:3128 -t foobar .
```